# Sort 10 clock numbers

Tags: pattern, number-property

An electronic clock shows hours and minutes: from 00:00 to 23:59.

[image]

Sort the numbers 0, 1, ..., 9 according to the time of their presence on the clock board during the 24-hours.

**Edit**
For example, for the 1-minute time period of showing 14:44, you should count it as one minute of 1 and 4 each.

Comment: The question seems a little unclear.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "time of presence"? For example, for the 1-minute time period of showing 14:44, do you count it as one minute of 1 and three minutes of 4, or one minute of 1 and 4 each?

Comment: I think you mean number of times present.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker It still doesn't answer my question, as it is unclear whether we should count three 4's showing at once as three appearances or just one.

Comment: @Bubbler, in you example, for the 1-minute time period of showing 14:44, one should count it as one minute of 1 and 4 each.

Answer (score 12):

Since we are only asked to sort, not give actual counts, there is an easy proof that

> the order (most frequent to least frequent) is just 0,1,2,...
>  
>  Indeed, for each valid time containing digit d+1 but not d, the time with every d+1 replaced with d is also valid and this association is unique; hence d must be counted at least as often as d+1.
>  
>  Note that the photo in OP is a crucial hint because it clarifies that the clock shows leading zeros. This is necessary for the proof to work (and for the statement to hold) for d=0.

Answer (score 4):

Without the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag, I just wrote a short program and here is the output:

> 900, 900, 630, 495, 450, 450, 252, 252, 252, 252
>
>
>  These are the number of minutes of 0 - 9.

Here is the Python program:

> ```
> s = [0] * 10
> for a in range(24):
>     for b in range(60):
>         for m in {a // 10, a % 10, b // 10, b % 10}:
>             s[m] += 1
> print(s)
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to spoiler the code, but [this main-meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105736) explains how. I confirmed that this will work if you try it on your code.

Comment: @bobble Thank you, it works. I also tried to remove the `<code></code>`, and it seems that there is no difference.

Comment: There is a 'P' on the illustration.  That means it is a 12h display (with am/pm).

Comment: @FlorianF I noticed that too, but also the statement says "from 00:00 to 23:59", so it was a bit confusing and I just interpret the 'P' as something else. Also this doesn't change the answer a lot: simply replace $24$ with $12$ and multiply all the results by $2$.

Comment: @Florian, I have updated the illustration.

Comment: No more objection.